# what does the syntax () => {} mean in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been reading articles about Node.js and MQTT.
And I am strange to the syntax as:

```
client.on('connect', () => {
  // do something
})
```

the `() => {}` thing, is it like `function() {}` ready for callback?
Or does it have some specific usage? Is there some reference about that?

Comment: Nothing to do with `Node.js`. It's the new `ES6` way of writing (usually inline) functions.

Answer (score 1):

That is the [ES6 arrow function syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). It is similar to `function() {}`, along with lexically binding `this`.

```
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => { statements }
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => expression
         // equivalent to:  => { return expression; }

// Parentheses are optional when there's only one parameter:
(singleParam) => { statements }
singleParam => { statements }

// A function with no parameters requires parentheses:
() => { statements }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a shorthand for

```
client.on('connect', function() {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: There is more to arrow functions than just being a 'shorthand'. You neglected to mention its primary feature.